# CKEditor5: Cannot read property 'pluginName' of undefined

Tags: javascript, ckeditor

I am trying to make a custom image plugin for CKEditor which integrates with my custom-made image upload system. Mainly, I run into problems while setting up this plugin. When I load "out-of-the-box" plugins, everything works fine (also, when I remove my own plugin, everything works again as it used to).

I get the following console error:

```
main.511663b82f6b3e2bb9df.js?2754ab1fde8ef5d8fd3d:1322 TypeError: Cannot read property 'pluginName' of undefined
    at new ga (main.511663b82f6b3e2bb9df.js?2754ab1fde8ef5d8fd3d:360)
    at new Ul (main.511663b82f6b3e2bb9df.js?2754ab1fde8ef5d8fd3d:521)
    at new Lc (main.511663b82f6b3e2bb9df.js?2754ab1fde8ef5d8fd3d:643)
    at new pp (main.511663b82f6b3e2bb9df.js?2754ab1fde8ef5d8fd3d:1318)
    at n (main.511663b82f6b3e2bb9df.js?2754ab1fde8ef5d8fd3d:643)
    at new Promise (<anonymous>)
    at Function.create (main.511663b82f6b3e2bb9df.js?2754ab1fde8ef5d8fd3d:643)
    at Module.<anonymous> (main.511663b82f6b3e2bb9df.js?2754ab1fde8ef5d8fd3d:1322)
    at n (main.511663b82f6b3e2bb9df.js?2754ab1fde8ef5d8fd3d:1)
    at main.511663b82f6b3e2bb9df.js?2754ab1fde8ef5d8fd3d:1
```

I couldn't find anything about the property `pluginName`, apart from the following excerpt of [documentation over at CKEditor](https://ckeditor.com/docs/ckeditor5/latest/api/module_core_plugin-PluginInterface.html#static-member-pluginName):

> `pluginName` : String | undefined
>
> An optional name of the plugin. If set, the plugin will be available
>   in get by its name and its constructor. If not, then only by its
>   constructor.
>
> The name should reflect the constructor name.
>
> To keep the plugin class definition tight it is recommended to define
>   this property as a static getter:
>
> ```
> export default class ImageCaption {
>     static get pluginName() {
>         return 'ImageCaption';
>     }
> }
> ```
>
> Note: The native Function.name property could not be used to keep the plugin name because it will be mangled during code
>   minification.

Inserting this function into my plugin code did not work, so I am kind of lost here what the problem could be. I've included my code below. I've set it up according to the [CKEditor advanced setup, first option](https://ckeditor.com/docs/ckeditor5/latest/builds/guides/integration/advanced-setup.html#running-the-editor-method-1), made in Webpack.

Am I missing something, or is there a problem in my code?

---

### index.js

```js
import ClassicEditor from './ckeditor'; // ckeditor.js in the same folder
import ModelElement from '@ckeditor/ckeditor5-engine/src/model/element';
require("./css/index.css");
ClassicEditor
    // Note that you do not have to specify the plugin and toolbar configuration — using defaults from the build.
    .create( document.querySelector( '#editor' ))
    .then( editor => {
      editor.commands.get( 'imageStyle' ).on( 'execute', ( evt, args ) => {
          // ...
          // this snippet of code works; it concerns hooking into the default image plugin
          // ...
      } );
    } )
    .catch( error => {
        console.error( error.stack );
    } );
```

### ckeditor.js

```js
import ClassicEditorBase from '@ckeditor/ckeditor5-editor-classic/src/classiceditor';
import EssentialsPlugin from '@ckeditor/ckeditor5-essentials/src/essentials';
import UploadAdapterPlugin from '@ckeditor/ckeditor5-adapter-ckfinder/src/uploadadapter';
import AutoformatPlugin from '@ckeditor/ckeditor5-autoformat/src/autoformat';
import BoldPlugin from '@ckeditor/ckeditor5-basic-styles/src/bold';
import ItalicPlugin from '@ckeditor/ckeditor5-basic-styles/src/italic';
import ImagePlugin from '@ckeditor/ckeditor5-image/src/image';
import ImageCaptionPlugin from '@ckeditor/ckeditor5-image/src/imagecaption';
import ImageStylePlugin from '@ckeditor/ckeditor5-image/src/imagestyle';
import ImageToolbarPlugin from '@ckeditor/ckeditor5-image/src/imagetoolbar';
import ImageUploadPlugin from '@ckeditor/ckeditor5-image/src/imageupload';
import LinkPlugin from '@ckeditor/ckeditor5-link/src/link';
import ListPlugin from '@ckeditor/ckeditor5-list/src/list';
import ParagraphPlugin from '@ckeditor/ckeditor5-paragraph/src/paragraph';
import Highlight from '@ckeditor/ckeditor5-highlight/src/highlight';
import MediaEmbed from '@ckeditor/ckeditor5-media-embed/src/mediaembed';
import Table from '@ckeditor/ckeditor5-table/src/table';
import TableToolbar from '@ckeditor/ckeditor5-table/src/tabletoolbar';

import ImageLibrary from './js/image-library.js'; // file containing the code for my custom plugin

export default class ClassicEditor extends ClassicEditorBase {}

ClassicEditor.builtinPlugins = [
    EssentialsPlugin,
    UploadAdapterPlugin,
    AutoformatPlugin,
    BoldPlugin,
    ItalicPlugin,
    Highlight,
    MediaEmbed,
    Table,
    TableToolbar,
    ImagePlugin,
    ImageCaptionPlugin,
    ImageStylePlugin,
    ImageToolbarPlugin,
    ImageUploadPlugin,
    LinkPlugin,
    ListPlugin,
    ParagraphPlugin,
    ImageLibrary // my custom plugin
];

ClassicEditor.defaultConfig = {
  highlight: {
        options: [
          {
                model: 'redPen',
                class: 'pen-red',
                title: 'Red pen',
                color: '#DD3300',
                type: 'pen'
            },
            {
                model: 'bluePen',
                class: 'pen-blue',
                title: 'Blue pen',
                color: '#0066EE',
                type: 'pen'
            },
            {
                model: 'greenPen',
                class: 'pen-green',
                title: 'Green pen',
                color: '#22AA22',
                type: 'pen'
            }
        ]
    },
    toolbar: {
        items: [
            //'heading',
            //'|',
            'bold',
            'italic',
            'link',
            'highlight:redPen', 'highlight:greenPen', 'highlight:bluePen', 'removeHighlight',
            '|',
            'bulletedList',
            'numberedList',
            '|',
            'mediaembed',
            'inserttable',
            '|',
            'undo',
            'redo'
        ]
    },
    image: {
        toolbar: [
            'imageStyle:full',
            'imageStyle:alignCenter',
            '|',
            'imageTextAlternative'
        ],
        styles: [
          'full','alignCenter'
        ]
    },
    table : {
      contentToolbar: [ 'tableColumn', 'tableRow', 'mergeTableCells' ]
    },
    language: 'nl'
};
```

### image-library.js

```js
import Plugin from '@ckeditor/ckeditor5-core/src/plugin';
import ModelElement from '@ckeditor/ckeditor5-engine/src/model/element';
import Command from '@ckeditor/ckeditor5-core/src/command';

class RoodCMSImageCommand extends Command {
    static get requires() {
        return [ ModelElement ];
    }
    execute( message ) {
      console.log(message);
    }
}
class ImageLibrary extends Plugin {
    static get requires() {
        return [ ModelElement ];
    }
    static get pluginName() {
        return 'ImageLibrary';
    }
    init() {
        // Initialize your plugin here.
        const editor = this.editor;
        console.log("plugin initialized.",editor);
    }
}
```

---

### Update: solution based on Maciej Bukowski's answer

Maciej pointed out that the class `ImageLibrary` (which I tried to import) lacked the `export`. Something that I've easily missed, was that whenever you're `import`ing something, you're going to have to also `export` it, otherwise it won't be available. The keywords `export default` did the trick for me.

The culprit was in image-library.js, for which I change the following line:

```js
class ImageLibrary extends Plugin {
    // ... this failed, as it missed the `export default` keywords
}
```

Into the following:

```js
export default class ImageLibrary extends Plugin {
    // ... works, as I properly export what I want to import.
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> import ImageLibrary from './js/image-library.js';

You don't export that library from a file, so that's why you have an error `Cannot read property 'pluginName' of undefined`. The `ImageLibrary` in the `ckeditor.js` becomes the `undefined` as it's can't be found in the `image-library` file.

Comment: Thanks. I added the keywords 'export default' in front of `class ImageLibrary`, which made it work. I guess it's a classic beginners' mistake. Apologies! Will update my question with the solution based on your answer!

Answer (score 0):

This error may happen again with the new `^37.0.1` release.

For me, the error was that I imported an element with a `lowercase`. Which is wrong.

So strikethrough should have been **S**trikethrough

[image]